# Does the Maxwell Boltzmann velocity distribution deal with the velocity of centre of mass

Tags: kinetic-theory, boltzmann-equation

Very basic question here. Does the Maxwell Boltzmann velocity distribution deal with the speed of the centre of masses of multiatomic( like Nitrogen ,oxygen) species  or with the exact speeds of atoms?

Comment: By "multiatomic species" you mean molecules or gas mixtures?

Comment: I've edited it. I meant molecules of gas mixtures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motion of a rigid body in mechanics is usually decomposed in the motion of its center-of-mass and the rotation about this center, and possibly also internal vibrations. It is simply a matter of convenience - one could, in principle, consider motions of separate atoms.

Thus, statistical mechanics one usually treats velocity components of the center-of mass of the molecules, rotations of the molecules, and vibrations of atoms in respect to each other as separate degrees of freedom. These degrees of freedom are all included on equal footing, e.g., each of them is associated with average energy $k_BT$, etc.

Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is a particular form of macrocanonical distribution that is usually presented in the introductory chapters of books on statistical mechanics, whereas the multi-atomic species are treated later. Thus, technically speaking, Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution describes only the centers-of-mass - just because it is a particular case of a statistical distribution.

Comment: So the distribution $d N(v)=N\left(\frac{m}{2 \pi k T}\right)^{3 / 2} e^{-m v^{2} / 2 k t} 4 \pi v^{2} d v$ are the velocities of the centre of masses.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: it is a distribution function, so what you said suggests that the center of mass may have many velocities?

Comment: @Buraian it may have many velocity components, each of which is a degree of freedom.

Comment: Thank you dear Vadim.